# how to set the checkbox to inactive when it is already used in the database - thymeleaf spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

I have a reservation application that stores tickets in h2 database using jpa. When someone booked a seat, the checkbox should be inactive/disabled for next people, because for now you can reserve the seat over and over again - user should see that some seats are already reservated.. How to solve this problem? Do I have to add something at  in reservation-seat.html?

reservation-seat.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Movies</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container my-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container my-5">
                <h1 th:text="${movieName}"> Movie Name</h1>

                <form th:action="@{'/reservation/save/' + ${repertoireId}}" th:object="${seatInfo}" method="post">

                    <div class="seatStructure">
                        <center>

                            <table id="seatsBlock">
                                <p id="notification"></p>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="14">
                                        <div class="screen">SCREEN</div>
                                    </td>

                                    <br/>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                    <td>8</td>
                                    <td>9</td>
                                    <td>10</td>
                                    <td>11</td>
                                    <td>12</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>A</td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A1"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A2"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A3"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A4"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A5"></td>
                                    <td class="seatGap"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A6"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A7"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A8"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A9"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A10"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A11"></td>
                                    <td><input th:field="*{seatReservation.seat}" type="checkbox" class="seats" value="A12"></td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                            <input type = "hidden" th:value="${movieName}">
                            <input type = "hidden" th:value="${repertoireId}">

                            </br>
                            <button type="submit">Order.</button>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <br/><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ReservationController.java

```
@Controller
// @Transactional
public class ReservationController {

    TicketRepo ticketRepo;
    ReservationRepo reservationRepo;
    AppUserRepo appUserRepo;
    MovieRepo movieRepo;
    RepertoireRepo repertoireRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ReservationController(TicketRepo ticketRepo, ReservationRepo reservationRepo, AppUserRepo appUserRepo,
                                 MovieRepo movieRepo, RepertoireRepo repertoireRepo) {
        this.ticketRepo = ticketRepo;
        this.reservationRepo = reservationRepo;
        this.appUserRepo = appUserRepo;
        this.movieRepo = movieRepo;
        this.repertoireRepo = repertoireRepo;
    }


    @GetMapping("/movies/{movieName}/reservation")
    public String reservationPage(Model model, @PathVariable ("movieName") String movieName) {


        Movie movie = movieRepo.findByTitle(movieName);
        List<Repertoire> repertoires = repertoireRepo.findByMovieId(movie.getId());

//        model.addAttribute("seat", new SeatReservation());
//        model.addAttribute("movieName", movirepertoireseName);

        model.addAttribute("repertoires", repertoires);
        return "reservation";
    }

    @GetMapping("/movies/{movieName}/reservation/{repertoireId}")
    public String reservationSeatPage(Model model, @PathVariable("movieName") String movieName,
                                  @PathVariable("repertoireId") Long repertoireId) {

        Testing testing1 = new Testing();
        testing1.setSeatReservation(new SeatReservation());
        model.addAttribute("seatInfo", testing1);
        model.addAttribute("movieName", movieName);
        model.addAttribute("repertoireId", repertoireId);
        return "reservation-seat";
    }

    @PostMapping("/reservation/save/{repertoireId}")
    public String reserve(@ModelAttribute ("seatInfo") Testing testing, Principal principal,
                          @ModelAttribute("repertoireId") Long repertoireId) {

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.setSeat(testing.getSeatReservation().getSeat());
        ticket.setPrice(20);
        ticket.setUuid(uuid);
        ticketRepo.save(ticket);


        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();

        reservation.setTicket(ticketRepo.findByUuid(uuid).get());
        Repertoire repertoire = repertoireRepo.findById(repertoireId).get();
        reservation.setMovie(movieRepo.findByTitle(repertoire.getMovie().getTitle()));
        reservation.setRepertoire(repertoire);
        reservation.setAppUser(appUserRepo.findByUsername(principal.getName()));
        reservationRepo.save(reservation);
        return "redirect:/movies/list";
    }
}
```

SeatReservation.java

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SeatReservation {

    private String seat;
    private boolean active;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

Testing.java

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Testing {

    private SeatReservation seatReservation;

    private Long id;
    private String string;
    private boolean active;

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

}
```

Ticket.java

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;


@Data
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private UUID uuid;
    private String seat;
    private Integer price;

    public Ticket() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Book seats dynamicalpy using javascript ajax and get the occupied seats in response and disable checkboxes based on that.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I never used js - is there other way to solve this problem, or it is few minutes an its done?

Comment: Ok let me add that in the answer section broadly.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on something similar to this so will post my approach.

I had used ajax to submit to post the seat booking info and if the response is successful then I will make the clicked checkbox/checkboxes disable.

As you said in comment section that you want to achieve this without javascript then go for below approach.

Every time you submit the form, save the occupied seats map (seat id key, status value) in model attribute and then iterate through the map by checking the seat id and status (active/inactive) and make rendered checkbox disabled/ not disabled based on the flag.